# How to reuse class library from existing solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, dll, code-reuse, csproj

I would like some advice please.

I am about to start a new MVC application using Visual Studio 2013. I would like the new solution to reuse 3 projects (Class Libraries) from an older solution which was created in Visual Studio 2010.

I don't understand how I should reference these 3 class library projects in my new solution. Should I from my new solution:

1. Add --> Existing Project --> locate the .csproj file of the project I want to reuse

OR

2. Add Reference --> locate the .dll file of the project I want to reuse

Would either of these be the correct approach?

Any feedback much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The DLL, not the csproj.